# Jinja show the biggest number

Tags: list, loops, jinja2

Jinja2: 2.7.2
Ansible: 2.9.9

Hi!

How I can select the most biggest number from list with jinja2?

#### Code:

- yml file :

```
 list:
   - 1
   - 2
   - 3
   - 4
```

- j2 file:

This code repeat the phrase for all elements in list

```
{% for i in list %}
The high number is: {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Desired result:

Only one phrase with the biggest number.

```
The high number is: 4
```

Cordially,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found:

I put "| max" in my code:

```
{% for i in list %}
The high number is: {{ i | max }}
{% endfor %}
```

thank's